# Do all the components defined in a wix project get included in a final msi?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, heat

When using Heat to auto generate it seems to create a whole bunch more components than what we want to actually ship.

For instance, Have a service that needs to be installed, so we want to do service registration stuff, and it is also a com component so we want to do com registration.  This is all in an MSVC# project and including the project into the install project in wix automatically ran heat on it (I just meant to setup a dependency for build) and the output included hundreds of components.

If you want to allow for some dynamic portion - say change to the com registration - without including everything - like pdb files - how is this best managed?

When you include this heat file into your project, how would you specify which components make up which features and which get ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the parameters along with which extension files you want and which to exclude.

Example

```
%1\Paraffin.exe -dir "..\..\..\..\Application" -dirref INSTALLLOCATION -custom App ..\..\AppFragment.wxs -guids -ext .vspscc -ext .cs -ext .resx -ext .csproj -ext .exclude -ext LocalAppSettings.config -ext .pdb -direXclude UITests -direXclude obj -direXclude Netrics -direXclude XSLT -multiple
```